# Prove that $\{ (x, x): x\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$, and is isomorphic to $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

> Given the diagonal $H = \{(x, x): x\in G\}$, show that
> (i) $H$ is a subgroup of $G\times G = G^2$ and; (ii) $H \cong G$

My attempt:

Proof.
(i) $G$ is a group, so an identity element $e\in G$ exists. By extension, $(e, e)\in H$. Let $x = (a, a), y = (b, b)$ for any two elements $a, b \in G$. Then $a, b \in H$. $G$ contains an inverse element, so $a^{-1}, b^{-1} \in G$. Then $x^{-1}, y^{-1}$ eixst on $H$, too. Therefore, $$y^{-1} = (b^{-1}, b^{-1}) \\
\implies xy^{-1} = (ab^{-1}, ab^{-1})\in H$$
$H$ is a subgroup of $G^2$.

(ii) Let $\phi: H \rightarrow G$ be defined by $\phi(a, a) = b$ where $(a, a)\in H$ and $b\in G$. If $\phi(a, a) = \phi (a', a')$ then necessarily we must have $a = a'$. $\phi$ is injective. The mapping $\rho: G\rightarrow H $ determined by $\rho(b) = (a, a)$ is injective since $(a, a) = (b, b)$ if and only if $a = b$. Hence, a bijection $H\rightarrow G$ exists.
Finally, consider the function $\mu(a) = (a, a)$. Then \begin{align*}\mu(ab) &= 
 (ab, ab) \\ &= (a, a)(b, b) \\ &= \mu(a)\mu(b)\end{align*}
gives us a homomorphism.

Therefore, $H$ is isomorphic to $G$. $\blacksquare$

Is there any flaw with my proof? Please let me know.

Comment: your proof is right, just some typos:in the fourth line, then a, b \in G have inverses, u need only to compute (a, a) (a^{-1},b^{-1}).another one is the definition of $\phi$, $\phi(a, a) =a $ not b. $\rho(a) =(a, a) $, why considering $\mu$? From the start u prove that $\rho$ and $\phi$ are homomorphisms and inverses to each other, hence isomorphisms, this proves the groups are isomorphic.

Comment: u can't prove that two groups are isomorphic by exbiting separately a bijection between them and the another map which u prove to be a homomorphism,u need to comme out with a single map whch is at the same time a homomorphism and a bijection.For example ,consider free groups $F_{2}$ and $F_{3}$ on two and three generators respectively ,then there are bijections between these two groups and homomorphisms but they aren't isomrphic.

Comment: Your map $\phi$ as it is defined does not make any sense: one wonders what this $b$ is. It should be: $\phi((a,a))=a$, with $a \in G$. This is clearly a bijective homomorphism between $H$ and $G$. Bonus question for you: prove that $H$ is *normal* in $G \times G$ if and only if $G$ is *abelian*.

Comment: @NickyHekster, In that case, how do I show that $\phi((a, a)) = a$ is onto?

Comment: Well, pick an arbitrary  $g \in G$, then $\phi$ maps $(g,g)$ onto $g$, so…

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the image of a group under a group homomorphism is a subgroup of the codomain group, then everything can be done at once by considering

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
\varphi: & G& \longrightarrow & H \subseteq G \times G\\
    & x & \longmapsto & (x,x) \end{array}$$

It is easy to prove that $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism, one-to-one as $\varphi^{-1}[\{(e,e)\}]=\{e\}$ and onto on $H$.

*Note: this however depends on where you’re in your groups course. In particular if you already covered or not group homomorphism theorems and product of groups.*